# How To Strongly Type Functions with Variable Arguments

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a Parser Combinator in Typescript. One of the functions is meant to take another function with any type signature and some number of arguments, then call it:

```
function f(func, ...args) {
  func.apply(null, args);
}
```

Is there any way to strongly type this so that the function can be called like this:

```
f(
  (s: string) => { console.log(s) },
  "Hello world!"
)
```

But have it fail with incorrectly typed arguments, or an incorrect number of them?

```
f(
  (s: string) => { console.log(s) },
  1234.56 // incorrect type
)

f(
  (s: string) => { console.log(s) },
  "Hello",
  "World" // too many arguments
)
```

(Some additional processing happens in `f`, which is why I don't just call `func` directly).

Comment: Do you mean for *any* function and its arguments, or specifically for the one you show? I mean, `f(func: (s: string) => void, arg: string): void` would work for what you've shown, but I get the feeling it's not that easy...

Comment: Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14719

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I was hoping to pass in any function with any signature. Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Yeah, figured as much. @NathanFriend's link shows that it's not there yet. [Here's another issue regarding "variadic kinds"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) which is what you want, but not in TypeScript at the moment. For now, you'd have to define the arguments lists via overloads.

Comment: @NathanFriend and Mike - good to know, thanks! I wasn't aware of the term "variance kinds" until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't do this for an arbitrary number of arguments, you can define a function that checks this for a limited number of arguments, and add more as needed:

```
function f<T1>(func: (a1: T1) => void, a1: T1): void;
function f<T1, T2>(func: (a1: T1, a2: T2) => void, a1: T1, a2: T2): void;
function f<T1, T2, T3>(func: (a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3) => void, a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3): void;
function f<T1, T2, T3, T4>(func: (a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3, a4: T4) => void, a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3, a4: T4): void;
// Private signature, not publicly available
function f(func: Function, ...args: any[]): void {
    func.apply(null, args);
}
f(
    (s: string) => { console.log(s) },
    1234.56 // incorrect type
)

f(
    (s: string) => { console.log(s) },
    "Hello",
    "World" // will accept more arguments  
)
```

The above version will check types, but it can be invoked with more arguments. This is because the overload with 2 generic types will be chosen, and the `func` can have fewer arguments and still be compatible.

You can achieve full safety, if you use a 2 call approach, which locks in the `func` in the first call, and returns a second function that already has the number of parameters decided:

```
function f2<T1>(func: (a1: T1) => void): (a1: T1) => void;
function f2<T1, T2>(func: (a1: T1, a2: T2) => void): (a1: T1, a2: T2) => void;
function f2<T1, T2, T3>(func: (a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3) => void): (a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3) => void;
function f2<T1, T2, T3, T4>(func: (a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3, a4: T4) => void): (a1: T1, a2: T2, a3: T3, a4: T4) => void;
// Private2 signature, not publicly available
function f2(func: Function) {
    return function (...args: any[]) { func.apply(null, args) };
}
f2((s: string) => { console.log(s) })(1234.56) // type mismatched 

f2((s: string) => { console.log(s) })(
    "Hello",
    "World" // too many arguments
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achive strong type safety:

```
function f<T extends any[], R>(func: (...args: T) => R, ...args: T) {
    func.apply(null, args);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).